# How to turn textbox contents into link

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I want to turn several words in textbox contents into a clickable links to another forms, if the word is recognized. Is that possible?

Comment: If it's a textbox, at what point does it become clickable as a link?  When the value is a valid url?

Comment: it should be predefined by me. for example. i should be able to provide it with array of strings that should be recognized as links.

Comment: So is a person typing the text in the textbox, then all of a sudden it turns into a link?

Comment: exactly. what, too fancy?

Comment: Nah, it could work a lot like it does on facebook.  Where if I'm typing a friends name, the text transforms into a button that I can click.  For some reason I thought this was a web application.  I'm way out of practice with winforms so I can't be of much help.  Sorry.  But the idea sounds neat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you check the value of the textbox each time it changes to see if it is a recognized word? If its a recognized word, you could style the text (make it blue and underlined) and set a boolean variable (`clickable`) to true. Then in a `Click` event, check to see if `clickable` is true, and if it is handle the event.

```
 boolean textbox1Clickable = false;

 public void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      string s = textbox1.Text;
      if(TextIsARecognizedWord(s))
      {
          //set the fore color of textbox1 to blue
          //set the font style of textbox1 to underlined
          textbox1Clickable = true;
      }
      else
      {
          //set the fore color of textbox1 to black
          //set the font style of textbox1 to normal (not underlined)
          textbox1Clickable = false;
      }
 }

 public void textbox1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
      if(textbox1Clickable)
      {
           //open your other form based on what is in textbox1.Text
      }
 }
```

Or do you want the textbox to actually turn into a link that cannot be typed into?

Comment: Yeah, so if you only wanted part of the text to be the link, I don't think my solution would work.